# Reading Unicode Characters using Selenium Webdriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to get the text of the following web element including its unicode character (Copyright symbol).

© 2021 ABC Inc. All rights reserved.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXduH.png)

I tried getWebDriver().findElement(elem).getText() but that gives me the following output.

**? 2021 ABC Inc. All rights reserved.**

I saw a few posts on this from earlier but still could not figure out how to go about reading this web element so that I capture unicode symbol (©) as well.

Appreciate any suggestions in this regard.
Thanks!

Comment: It's *very* possible that you're getting the right text, but fail when displaying it. How do you *output* the text?

Comment: Please include a small snippet of code that reads this data and then displays / prints it.

Comment: Hello Joachim, Andrew, here is the webelement/code/output.

Comment: (WebElement Definition)
private static final By copyrightMessage = By.xpath("//span[@class='login-copyright-msg']");

Comment: (CODE)
String copyright = getWebDriver().findElement(copyrightMessage).getText();
System.out.println(String.format("Copyright: %s", copyright));

Comment: (OUTPUT)
Copyright: ? 2021 ABC Inc. All rights reserved

Comment: so essentially, webdriver getText() method does not seem to preserve UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I am confused after finding that number 169 decimal is the COPYRIGHT SIGN character in *both* Unicode and Windows-1252. So I have no idea as to what is really going!

I will leave this Answer as-is in case the code is helpful to anyone trying to solve this mystery.

---

Likely due to a limited (non-[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)) character set and encoding in use by whatever means you generated your output.

Here is demo code showing your example string dumped to console via `System.out` by using the current default [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), using UTF-8, and using the limited [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

See this example [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/YPZGa4).

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets ;
import java.nio.charset.Charset ;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String blurb = "© 2021 ABC Inc. All rights reserved." ;
        
        // The character set and encoding currently in use by `System.out` is not known, some default.
        System.out.println( "----------|  default  |--------------------------" );
        System.out.println( "blurb: " + blurb ) ;  
        
        // Let's set the character set and encoding to UTF-8 by wrapping `System.out` in a `PrintStream`.
        System.out.println( "----------|  UTF-8  |--------------------------" );
        try
        {
            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream( System.out , true , StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name() );
            printStream.println( "blurb: " + blurb );
        }
        catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        // In contrast, try Windows-1252 character set.
        System.out.println( "----------|  windows-1252  |--------------------------" );

        // Verify windows-1252 charset is available on the current JVM.
        String windows1252CharSetName = "windows-1252";
        boolean isWindows1252CharsetAvailable = Charset.availableCharsets().keySet().contains( windows1252CharSetName );
        if ( isWindows1252CharsetAvailable )
        {
            System.out.println( "isWindows1252CharsetAvailable = " + isWindows1252CharsetAvailable );
        } else
        {
            System.out.println( "FAIL - No charset available for name: " + windows1252CharSetName );
        }

        // Print the blurb.
        try
        {
            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream( System.out , true , windows1252CharSetName );
            printStream.println( "blurb: " + blurb );
        }
        catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

When run.

```
----------|  default  |--------------------------
blurb: © 2021 ABC Inc. All rights reserved.
----------|  UTF-8  |--------------------------
blurb: © 2021 ABC Inc. All rights reserved.
----------|  windows-1252  |--------------------------
isWindows1252CharsetAvailable = true
blurb: � 2021 ABC Inc. All rights reserved.
```

As expected, we see the [COPYRIGHT SIGN](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a9/index.htm) character (code point 169 decimal) appear properly for Unicode but fail for Windows-1252. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252),

---

Recommended reading: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Thanks Basil! This definitely works for me. What I was referring to is getting an element value using getWebDriver().findElement(By).getText() method. That only returns ? for the unicode character. Wondering if there is some other way to use selenium webdriver to get the string with unicode char.

Comment: @Saurabh After getting your Comment, I did some more checking. Yikes! The number 169 decimal in *both* Unicode and Windows-1252 happens to coincidentally be the COPYRIGHT SIGN character. So now I am very confused. I have no idea what might be going on here.

Comment: The co-occurance of the Copyright sign is pretty clear: Windows-1252 is a derivation/based on ISO-8859-1 and the Unicode standard was created in a way that its codepoints are a superset of ISO-8859-1 (i.e. all ISO-8859-1 characters are encoded with the same value as their Unicode codepoints).